Where can I find hardware details for the Philips VG-5000?
I'm interested in exactly what connectors the VG-5000 and what the pinouts are for them. Ideally, I'd like a full set of schematics for the machine.

Well, the wikipedia article links to the service manual (see Reference 23), and though it is in French, it contains the pinout for the connectors and complete schematics.
(Took me a few minutes to find, less then writing it up).
